# Не устанавливается wine mono

Tags: mono

Пробовал ставить разными методами:

С помощью winetricks (не работает, крч):

```
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet45
Executing load_dotnet45
------------------------------------------------------
This package may not work on a 64-bit installation
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
reg: не удалось найти указанный раздел реестра или значение
Executing rm -f /root/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/mscoree.dll
Executing w_do_call dotnet35
Executing load_dotnet35
------------------------------------------------------
dotnet35 does not yet fully work or install on wine.  Caveat emptor.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet30sp1
Executing load_dotnet30sp1
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet30
Executing load_dotnet30
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by nekto.)
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by nekto.)
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by nekto.)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
isPrimaryInstance
------------------------------------------------------
Please download netframework3.exe from http://www.oldversion.com/download-.Net-Framework-3.0.html, place it in /root/.cache/winetricks/dotnet30, then re-run this script.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Если запускаю без прав супер-пользователя, то говорит, что в доступе отказано. Если пробовать установить netframework3.exe с помощью wine пишет "Для установки и настройки Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 x86 необходимо использовать средство управления ролями.". Я хз, что это значит.

Пробовал поставить wine-mono-5.1.0-x86.msi с помощью wine64 uninstaller (не работает, крч):

```
002c:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
002c:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
002c:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
```

Помогите, пж. Моя система - Debian 10.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь установить mono используя сам вайн? Вот шаги установки моно в дебиан https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian

Comment: Спасибо, только что сделал все это. Но все равно говорит ```000f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
0009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed```